# How to add a new BigQuery table data to Tableau extract?

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

Is it possible to add data from a new BigQuery table to existing Tableau extract?

For example, there are BigQuery tables partitioned by date like access_20160101, access_20160102, ... and data from 2016/01/01 to 2016/01/24 is already in Tableau server extract. Now a new table for 2016/01/25, access_20160125 has been created and I want to add the data to the existing extract, but don't want to read the old tables because there is no change in them but loading them will be charged by Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly: you created an extract for a table in BigQuery and now you want to append data in a different table to that extract.

As long as both tables have exactly the same column names and data types in those columns you can do this:

1. Create an extract from the new table.
2. Append that extract to the old one. (see: [add data from a file](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.html#extracting_addfromfile.html))

Now you have one extract with the data of both tables.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you can add data from another extract. Is there any way to schedule the operations?

Comment: You cannot schedule this from Tableau Desktop. If you want to schedule this kind of thing take a look at the Extract API (http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/sdk/en-us/help.htm#SDK/tableau_sdk.htm). Also, if this answer solves your question then you can accept it by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: Thank you! Will check the Extract API!